# Cannot select text in KO Grid

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, kogrid

In kogrid I cannot select any text in the grid. You can see this here in their examples

http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/#/examples

Is there anyway I can make it be able to select the text in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because of the default kogrid.css having this section

```
.kgNoSelect{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Fork the code, and remove this definition, and you should be able to select the text.

Answer (score 0):

It is builded with **Knockoutjs**, so there is an Observable of the text you need to select, I'm sure.

I don't know this KO Grid, but knowing KO what you need to do is just to see which one is the `ko.observable()` you need and create a custom function for your purposes.